# PHP script only returns first row of SELECT statement

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I have a php script to run mssql queries. When I run a query like, "SELECT first_name, last_name, mi FROM users", all I get back is 'first_name'. Here's the script:

```
<?php

require '../../scripts/database_connection.php';

$query_text = $_REQUEST['query'];
$result = mssql_query($query_text);

 if (!result) {
   die("<p>Error: " . $query_text ."</p>");
}

$return_rows = true;
 if (preg_match("/^\s*(CREATE|INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE|DROP)/i,
   trim(strtoupper($query_text)))) {
  $return_rows = false;
}

if ($return_rows) {
 echo "<p>Results from your query:</p>";
 echo "<ul>";

while ($row = mssql_fetch_row($result)) {
 echo "<li>{$row[0]}</li>";
}

 echo "</ul>";
}

 else {

  if ($result) {
   echo "<p>Your query was processed successfully.</p>";
   echo "<p>$query_text</p>";
 }
}

?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You always echo only the first element (`$row[0]`)

Comment: taking the mssql query via query string and execute it, dont this seem  like a big security hole?

Comment: it absolutly IS a huge security risk. I assume it is only a local test script. If not, never accept outside parameters ($_REQUEST) as input for executable code (like a query) and never use unfiltered variables.

Answer (score 1):

A $row is an array with all columns of your select. Just iterate with foreach or implode it:

```
while ($row = mssql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<li>".implode(" - ", $row)."</li>";
}
```

You might also want to use mssql_fetch_assoc to get the respective column names:

- http://php.net/manual/de/function.mssql-fetch-row.php
- http://php.net/manual/de/function.mssql-fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to access $row[1] and $row[2]?

```
    while ($row = mssql_fetch_row($result)) {
     echo "<li>{$row[0]} - {$row[1]} - {$row[2]}</li>";
    }
```